# ¿Como hacer para que mi JSON se muestre en la misma página (AJAX) usando PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

EDITO de nuevo

Tengo un formulario HTML donde el usuario ingresa los datos que desea buscar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>HPI</title>
    <script>

        function realizaProceso(nodoHpi, nombreIndice, valorIndice){

        $('#formulario').on('submit', (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault();
        });

       var parametros = {"index": nodoHpi, "name":nombreIndice, "value":  valorIndice};

        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   'php/json.php',
                type:  'post',

                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#respuesta").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                    var json = JSON.stringify(response);
                        $("#respuesta").html(json);
                        console.log(json);
                        console.log(nodoHpi, nombreIndice, valorIndice);

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <br>
        <br>
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="formulario">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nodoHpi">Nodo Hpi</label>
            <input type="text" name="nodoHpi" id="nodoHpi" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombreIndice">Nombre Indice</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombreIndice" id="nombreIndice" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="valorIndice">Valor Indice</label>
            <input type="text" name="valorIndice" class="form-control" id="valorIndice">
            </div>

            <div class="boton">
            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="realizaProceso($('#nodoHpi').val(), $('#nombreIndice').val(), $('#valorIndice').val());return false;">ENVIAR CONSULTA</button><br>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="ajax">
        <span id="respuesta"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este formulario es procesado por mi archivo PHP y me devuelve un JSON con los valores ingresados en el formulario. Si los datos no coinciden entonces me devuelve un arreglo vacío.

Mi archivo PHP:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$nodoHpi= (isset($_POST['index']))?$_POST['index']:null;
$nombreIndice= (isset($_POST['value']))?$_POST['value']:null;
$valorIndice= (isset($_POST['name']))?$_POST['name']:null;

if($nodoHpi && $valorIndice && $nombreIndice){

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_PORT => "12530",
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://***.**.**.**:12530/search",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"token\": \"1\",
        \n\t\"query\": [{\n\"index\": $nodoHpi,
            \n\t\t\"terms\": [{\n\t\t\t\"name\": $nombreIndice,
                \n\t\t\t\"value\": $valorIndice,
                \n\t\t\t\"operator\": \"like\"\n\t\t}],
                \n\t\t\"results\": {\n\t\t\t\"count\": 5000,
                    \n\t\t\t\"sort\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\"name\": \"ISSUE_DATE\",
                        \n\t\t\t\t\"order\": \"descending\"\n\t\t\t}],
                        \n\t\t\t\"fields\": []\n\t\t}\n\t}]\n}"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    echo "No se han encontrado resultados para su busqueda";
} else {
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo $response;
}

}else{
    $a = array();
    $a['error']='Todos los campos son obligatorios';
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($a);
}
```

El ajax me está andando bien pero me devuelve solamente lo que coincide con el indice **{"results":[{"index":"ALTC.MC_ROBERTS","hits":[]}]}** cuando la respuesta esperada debería ser mucho más larga !

La respuesta con los mismos parámetros realizada con el POSTMAN es muchisimo más larga.

Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando ??

Comment: Aquí mismo hay varios ejemplos, es sólo [cuestión de buscar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bajax%5D+misma+página) o de revisar [las preguntas de la etiqueta `ajax`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax).

Comment: Si vas a trabajar con json, te recomiendo trabajarlo como array asociativo y despues usando la función `json_encode` convertirlo en json. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar jquery y ajax para enviar los datos de tu formulario y no hacerlo por el form te dejo este codigo donde debe poner los datos que recibiras en tu web service dentro de la propiedad data, y en la propiedad success hasta ahora mostrara la respuesta mediante una alerta lo cual puedes cambiar para que se escriba en tu div o una etiqueta `<pre>` para que se vea mejor.

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "/php/json.php", 
 type: "POST", 
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
 dataType: "json", 
 data: "", 
 success: function (response) { 
 alert(response);
 }, 
 error: function () { 
 alert("error"); 
 } 
 });
```